# Optimize Apache serving as backend behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, hosting, performance-tuning

Apache (2.4.x) is a well known server and performance optimization is widely discussed and well documented.

Nevertheless, for those cases where Apache is reverse proxied (behind Nginx or other any other software), I'm wondering what best suits Apache as far as performance is involved.

Considering this very simple Nginx config:

```
server {
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_pass_header Content-type;
    }
}
```

Without giving actual values (which are strongly tied to hardware, trafic and application type), should the logic differ in certain ways compared to what is usually applied for front servers?

For instance, as we're talking server to server (hardware) – and often even both servers (software) communicate on localhost – is `keepalive` a good practice? If yes, is there a baseline to start with?

Will Apache see the all Nginx request as one same client or one of `X-Real-IPX-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` will make Apache consider requests coming from different clients?

I guess that as far as Apache is concerned, a client is *IP_SRC:Port*.

I mean that if all requests proxied through Nginx are considered as one client, how will Apache respect `MaxConnectionsPerChild`?

How will Apache with `mod_prefork` will fork (or not) workers? In this mod, clients and workers are a 1:1 relation. And as workers aren't able to handle more than one client at a time, will requests will be queued until there's a free worker available?

Is there best practices one should be aware of for this kind of setting?

Is there a mod that sould be preffered over the other? Or should one mod be avoided?

Comment: First: Do you even need Apache at all? In this case you probably don't.

Comment: I have to support a php app that heavily relies on Apache and can't use php fmp